# Recognizing and getting value(s) from pre-defined sentences using PHP (Regex?)

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP I would like to recognize pre-defined sentences in a string, and outputting the word which is positioned at ´target`. I **think** this could probably be done using regex, but I don't have the knowledge to write it.

Sentence examples:

1. where is the airport *target* located?
2. how many airports are there in *target*?
3. how long does a flight between *target* and *target* take?

Desired output examples (as an array):

1. 0=>heathrow
2. 0=>france
3. 0=>barcelona, 1=>paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use regular expressions, via [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$input = 'where is the airport heathrow located?';

$templates = [
    '/where is the airport (.*) located\?/i',
    '/how many airports are there in (.*)\?/i',
    '/how long does a flight between (.*) and (.*) take?/i',
];

foreach ($templates as $template) {
    if (preg_match($template, $input, $matches)) {
        var_dump($matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
string(8) "heathrow"
```

In your templates, use parentheses to surround the "variables" in your "templates". That defines a capturing subgroup, which PHP will yank out as part of the preg_match routine. Inside the parentheses, I use `.*` which means match everything. This may be too permissive. You might try, for example `\w+`, which means "one or more word-like characters".